# Prevent R Studio from 'skipping' comments. Run EACH line

Tags: r, comments, rstudio

After updating R Studio (i'm using 1.0.153), R ignores comments by skipping to the next executable line. I really don't like this, I prefer to send even comments to the console (the way it has always been before recent update). Is it possible to continue sending comments to the console?

Answer (score 2):

To send comments to the console: 
Go to Tools -> Options -> Code and uncheck "Execute all lines in a statement."

Comment: I think R Studio changed this again.  So it's Tools -> Options -> Code and change to "Ctrl+Enter executes: Current line".